# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1, trying to insert data in database

Tags: java, database

```
private static final String DB_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
private static final String DB_USER = "scott";
private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "tiger";




public static void main(String[] argv) {

    try {

        createTable();
        insertRecordIntoTable("leo","123");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

}

private static void createTable() throws SQLException {

    Connection dbConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    String createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE DBUSER1("
            + "USER_ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, "
            + "USERNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
            + "PASSWORD VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, "
            + "PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID) "
            + ")";

    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(createTableSQL);

        System.out.println(createTableSQL);

        // execute create SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Table \"dbuser\" is created!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }

}

private static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
        return dbConnection;

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}

private static void insertRecordIntoTable(String username, String password) throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER1"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            // execute insert SQL stetement
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }
        }
}
```

}
I'm pretty sure the problem is when I try to insert data into the database but I cannot figure out why is this occurring. If there is anyone that can find my problem, please fill free to help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `preparedStatement.executeUpdate();` you need to set the parameter values using `setXXX()` method, like below:

```
preparedStatement.setInt(1, SOME_ID);
preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
preparedStatement.setString(3, password);
```

Those are the statements that substitutes the value of the parameters in the query.

Comment: Thank you I will try this at school tomorrow

Comment: with the statement: insertRecordIntoTable("leo","123"); in my main method, would this be inserted in my database afterwards?  Thanks

Comment: Yes it will, provided you set all the 3 parameters `correctly`